# Fixed screen border

Tags: c#, drawing

I am writing a C# solution where I have one pc with keyboard and mouse and other two with screen only. I can control them remotely with the peripherals on the main pc.

What I would like to do is to have a colored border (Skype shared desktop like) when I control one of the remote screens, to notify which one i am using.

I've tried with the graphics and DrawRectangle but it is not fixed and part of it goes away if i move the form window over it, since it refreshes the graphics. 
I would like to know if there is a way to add the border and then remove it when i switch the remote control.

Is there any solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, your form may repaint at any time.

Instead of drawing directly, you need to handle the `Paint` event and draw whatever is necessary.

When you want to change what is drawn, just call `Invalidate()` to trigger another `Paint` event.

Comment: But does this work even for the desktop screen? Or only inside the form?

Comment: If you want to paint on the desktop, make a transparent form (learn about layered windows) that covers it and only draw the parts you want.   You may also want to handle WM_NCHITTEST to make the mouse pass through it.